# Dropdown list based on another dropdown list MS-Access

Tags: ms-access

I want to generate a drop down list in MS Access that is generated based on another drop down list.

For example, I have a service which might be Endo, Exo or Mri.

If the user chooses Endo from the drop down, the service type available can be treatment or retreatment. If he chooses Exo, it can be other options.

How can I do this in MS Access?

Answer (score 1):

See the below article. Article is written in Bengali but you will get a sample file and some screenshot which will help you, how to do that.

[Dependable Combo Box](http://harun24hr.blogspot.com/2016/01/ms-access-dependable-combo-box.html)